# Update multiple row using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php and mySql. I'm trying to update multiple row by using php and mysql.

I'm having problem with updating multiple row in MySQL database. It's only update the last row  of the table in the database. For example, user click on view product. The page will list 10 product that currently in the database. And user wants to update product information by on-click method. After finishing update, user click submit.

The problem is it only capture and update information of the last product in the table. I tried to put it in the foreach() function. But it doesnt work.

Please help. I just learned PHP and mySQL less than a week. I very much appreciate any helps.

```
<?php
include 'dbconn.inc.php';
include 'functions.inc.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);

while( $row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
$products($row['id']) = 'id';
}

$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['id'] );
$weight = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['weight'] );
$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['name'] );
$supplier_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['supplier_id'] );
$price = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['price'] );
$description = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['description'] );

foreach( $products as $id){
$sql = "UPDATE products
    SET
        `id` = '$id',
        `weight` = '$weight',
        `price` = '$price',
        `name` = '$name',
        `supplier_id` = '$supplier_id',
        `description` = '$description'

    WHERE `id` = '$id'";

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work?"  It doesn't look like you ever try to run the query

Comment: Please, do not do escaping like this. Use [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Where did you learn to do it this way?

Comment: The query is running but the it only updated the last row in database

Comment: @tadman I learned it from my friend

Comment: @user1754822 I honestly think it's because you're declaring `$id` twice. Are you trying to set the value of `id` in your database to the `$_POST` data?

Comment: @user1754822 Well your friend isn't as up to date as he *could* be

Comment: @Evan yes, i think that what i am trying to do

Comment: @user1754822 Then you're going to have to refer to my *latest* update, I moved the values around

Comment: You should probably get some better reference material, then. Seems like you and your friend have some catching up to do. For one, developing sites like this is time consuming and error prone, something many [popular PHP frameworks](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) address by providing proven, reliable solutions to common problems as well as providing a large amount of community supplied add-ons you can leverage. Writing SQL like this is never fun and is best avoided.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. First, you're declaring the variable `$id` twice.
2. You should be using the `$key` not the `$value` in the loop

Instead, try this:

```
foreach( $products as $key => $value){
$sql = "UPDATE products
    SET
        `id` = '$id',
        `weight` = '$weight',
        `price` = '$price',
        `name` = '$name',
        `supplier_id` = '$supplier_id',
        `description` = '$description'

    WHERE `id` = '$key'";

 }
```

The reason for using the array `key` rather than its `value` is because in the below line you are setting the `key` of the array to the values returned from the first query:

```
while( $row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
    $products($row['id']) = 'id';
}
```

I might suggest instead doing this:

```
$products = array();

while( $row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
    $products[]['id'] = $id;
}

    foreach( $products as $product){
    $sql = "UPDATE products
        SET
            `id` = '$id',
            `weight` = '$weight',
            `price` = '$price',
            `name` = '$name',
            `supplier_id` = '$supplier_id',
            `description` = '$description'

        WHERE `id` = '" . $product['id'] . "'";

     }
```

Comment: @user1754822 I updated, I am only able to guess here until you reply to the comments, but I think you want to set the value to the POST data, and update the row in the `foreach` - is that right?

Comment: @user1754822 do an `echo $sql` to make sure the query has the values you expect it to at each run

Comment: @user1754822 Don't bother, it was my fault. If you used the second solution I posted, the array should have been made like this: `$products[]['id'] = $id;`

Comment: I think your part is correct. There might be issues in other files. Thank you for your time and help. Have a good one!

Comment: You absolutely must fix all your [SQL injection issues](http://bobby-tables.com/php) if you're intending to publish this to the general internet. There are [automatic tools](http://sqlmap.org/) that can do a very long list of terrifying things if you forget to escape even one variable, so switch to using placeholders as soon as possible.

Comment: @tadman This is just for class project. But I learned something new today from here. Definitely I will apply for future project. Thanks again!